# Ruby, removing parts a file path

Tags: ruby

```
$local_path_to_css_file = File.expand_path(filename)
```

gives me

```
A/B/C/D/CSS/filename
```

or

```
A/B/C/D/CSS/layouts/filename
```

I want the result to be:

```
css/filename
```

or

```
css/layouts/filename
```

to remove everything up until `css/`.

Comment: `File.expand_path` will always return the absolute path to what is passed in. You'd have to `gsub` something like `/^C:\/MyPath/` to a blank string.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `Pathname`

```
require 'pathname'

absolute_path = Pathname.new(File.expand_path(filename))
project_root  = Pathname.new("/A/B/C/D") # you can set up root somewhere else, e.g. at point where script starts
relative      = absolute_path.relative_path_from(project_root)

relative.to_s # => "css/filename"
```

Comment: This solution assumes that a file extension is not present in the `filename` variable and that the Question is asking for a solution without the file extension.

If your filename has the file extension and you desire it, this solution works as is.  If you do not desire the extension, remove it with the [`sub_ext` method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-sub_ext) like this:

`relative.sub_ext('').to_s`

Answer (score 4):

A look-behind pattern will match your need.

```
def my_path(s)
  s[/(?=CSS).*/]
end

my_path "A/B/C/D/CSS/filename"  # => CSS/filename
```

Comment: lookbehind has signature of `/(?<=...)/` though. but that's a great way. see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html